# Find $\beta$ as an element of $S_7$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\beta^8 = (1$ $5$ $4$ $3$ $6$), a 5-cycle. Find $\beta$ as an element of $S_7$.

Any help would be appreciated on this problem. I do not have one similar to this. Thanks!

Comment: How do you write elements of $S_7$? Like this $\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5&6&7\\5&2&6&3&4&1&7\end{pmatrix}$? This is the notation in which the top row are all the numbers from 1 to 7, and the numbers below them are the numbers to which the permutation sends them. The notation in which $\beta$ was given gives a number followed by the number to which the permutation sends them. The numbers that are mising, like 2 or 7 are supposed to be fixed.

Comment: @Hellen i just realized i had a typo...$\beta ^8$ is defined as so. it asks to find $\beta$ as an element

Comment: Ok, now it is not just reading notation but doing a computation as well.

Comment: what's that computation?

Comment: To find $\beta$ given the cycle decomposition of $\beta^8$ first observe that a power cannot merge cycles, it can only split them. The cycle $(1,5,4,3,6)$ can only come from a cycle of larger or equal order. But the order of such cycle must be divisible by $5$. Therefore it can only come from a cycle $c$ of order $5$. Since $e=c^{5}$ we have $c^{8\times2}=c^{16}=c$. Now the elements $2$ and $7$ are fixed by $\beta^8$. Either $\beta$ fixed them too, or $(2,7)$ was a cycle of $\beta$. We get two solutions Either $\beta=(1,5,4,3,6)^2(2)(7)$ or $\beta=(1,5,4,3,6)^2(2,7)$.

Comment: So, either $\beta = (1,4,6,5,3)(2)(7)$ or $\beta=(1,4,6,5,3)(2,7)$. Now you can write them in the other notation.

Comment: I understand why the cycle must be divisible by 5 since it is a 5-cycle. however how do you know $e=c^5$ and then how do you get $c^{8x2}$?

Comment: A 5-cycle has order $5$. Therefore if you rotate the elements $5$ times they return to the original position, i.e. you get the identity permutation. The other question: $c^{8\times2}=c^{16}=c^{3\times 5+1}=c^{3\times5}c=(c^5)^3c=e^3c=c$.

Comment: for my second question...do we even need that fact to answer the question? what is $c$ exactly?

Comment: $c$ is a cycle such that $c^8=(1,5,4,3,6)$. Notice that $\beta$ satisfies the same equation, but in this case I am looking only for solutions that are cycles, that is why I needed a new name $c$.

Comment: makes sense...another question: why did you multiply 8 by 2? is there a particular reason

Comment: $2$ is the inverse of $8$ mod $5$ in the sense that $2\times8$ is $1$ mod $5$.

Answer (score -2):

It is enough to find $\beta$ that is a $5$-cycle.

Then $\beta^{5}=1$ and so $\beta = \beta^{16} = (1 5 4 3 6)^2$.

Comment: Why the downvotes?